# How can i use store a java file physically in my computer for a particular commit using jgit?

Tags: git, jgit

In git i used ,

```
git show commitid : filename >> commitid_filename.java
```

This statements basically stores the java code for the file mentioned for that commit. The file will be stored in my computer under the name `commitid_filename.java`. I will be running an iteration to store all the files updated in the commit. How can I do the same using Jgit?

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: A sample snippet that can get you started is at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/ReadFileFromCommit.java